# NSTextAttachment and touch events

Tags: ios7, uitextview, textkit

I have a UITextView (in edit mode) with few images (as NSTextAttachment). I'd like to intercept touch events on these.

I have set a delegate on the UITextView but `textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:` is never called.

(from the forums it seems that the UITextView's `editable` property should be `NO` for this to work, but not as per the official documentation)

The editor looks like this:
[image: Editor]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, `textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:` is not meant to work for editable text views. A way around this is to implement your own `UITapGestureRecognizer` and do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView*) self.view;
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = textView.textContainer;
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:textView];
    point.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
    point.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;

    NSUInteger characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];

    if (characterIndex >= textView.text.length)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }

    _textAttachment = [textView.attributedText attribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName atIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:&_range];
    if (_textAttachment)
    {
        return;
    }
    _textAttachment = nil;
}
```

Then you add this gesture recogniser to your text view and when the gesture is recognized you ask for the `_textAttachment` value.

Bear in mind that `characterIndexForPoint:inTextContainer: fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:` returns the nearest character index. You might want to check if the point is inside the attachment depending on what you're planning to do.

Comment: thanks, handling the touchesBegan:.. in my custom UITextView seems to be the way to go.

Comment: FYI, I had some trouble with touchesBegan in UITextView. It wasn´t always called.